# JSF: how to rendered=#{bean.isRendered} multiple components at one time

Tags: java, jsf

I tried this but does not work:

```
<f:verbatim rendered="#{bean.isRendered}">
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        ...
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        ...
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu>
        ...
    </h:selectOneMenu>                    
</f:verbatim>
```

I can put the `rendered` attributes inside each `<h:selectOneMenu>`, ohh well :D it would be easier if I group them like above

Comment: Side note: `f:verbatim` is intented to have **only** plain HTML inside, not JSF components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.someBoolean}">
    <!-- multiple elements here -->
</h:panelGroup>
```